# Style span only on the first line of div

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following html:

```
<div class="pp">TWO <span>WORDS</span>
</div>
```

And I want to separate them by "@" for example, but only if they are on the same line.
I don't want to use any JS, only CSS.

This is not working:

```
.pp{
    width:20%;
}
.pp::first-line  span:before{
    content: " @ "
}
```

And I couldn't come up with another idea.

Note that I want one and the same element to either have or not @ depending on if it appears on the same lane. E.g.

```
TWO @ WORDS
```

But

```
TWO
WORDS
```

Depending on the size of the window when the 20% can't fit the TWO @ WORDS, the WORDS gets on a second line, and then I want the "@" to disappear

Comment: Can you add some more html to show more than one line so we know what you mean by 'only on the same line'.  It'd be easier is we could see ones that you don't want to target as well as the ones you want to target.

Comment: Can't be done without JS, sorry. `::first-line does not match any real HTML element` (from MDN) so you can't target the span when it's on the first line.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious solution would be to use two spans (text should in text tags anyway and not text nodes).

Then you can target the **second** child and use `:before`.

```css
.pp {
  width: 20%;
}
.pp span:nth-child(2):before {
  content: '@';
}
```

```html
<div class="pp">
  <span>TWO</span>
  <span>WORDS</span>
</div>

<div class="pp">
  <span>ONE</span>
</div>
```

Comment: "text should in text tags anyway and not text nodes" Only because it makes it easier (possible) to target them via CSS.

Comment: @BoltClock True...but I'm kinda funny that way, I just think text nodes are poor practice. IMO only of course.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately that's not exactly what I intended. I have edited my question - I hope I explained better what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: CSS can't detect width of elements like that..so you may need to re-think your options,